# react navigation - how to change initial or root screen?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react native with react navigation for navigation. I added splash screen as inital screen :

```
const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Splash: SplashScreen,
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: deScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Splash",
    contentComponent: SideMenuScreen
  }
);
```

I am navigating to detail screen when i am click back using back button in android or calling following function to go back :

```
this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

goBack() close current screen and open initial screen i.e splash screen.

How to change root or initial screen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want users to be able to navigate to your Splash Screen. This means that you don't really want that screen as part of your drawer navigator.

For this purpose, react-navigation has a [`SwitchNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html) that allows you to switch between different navigation trees.

This would look something like:

```
const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Details: deScreen,
},
{
  initialRouteName: "Home",
  contentComponent: SideMenuScreen
});

const rootNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Splash: SplashScreen,
  App: AppNavigator
});
```

You can then navigate to `App` when you're done loading and the back button will always return to `Home` and not to the splash screen.

Comment: In react navigation 5.x createSwitchNavigator has been replaced by Authentication flows reference url : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

Answer (score 1):

Just change the order of the screens inside the first object of `createDrawerNavigator` or change the property of `initialRouteName`:

```
const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Splash: SplashScreen,
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: deScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    contentComponent: SideMenuScreen
  }
);
```

Or

```
const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
      {
        Home: HomeScreen,
        Splash: SplashScreen,
        Details: deScreen,
      },    
 );
```

Comment: Let me try and test

Answer (score 1):

By default, in `Drawer` and `Tab` navigators, triggering a `navigation.goBack()` will go back to the initialRouteName of that navigator.

To answer your question, you have 2 ways to solve this problem:

1) Wrap your `drawerNavigator` inside a `SwitchNavigator` where you have 2 screens, SplashScreen and then your `drawerNavigator`. Your drawer will then navigate to his initalRouteName that would be your `Home`.

2) Wrap your `HomeScreen` and `DetailsScreen` inside another navigator (for example a StackNavigator), and goBack trough that.

Update

An example for the solution #2 would be:

```
const homeStack=const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
                                       HomeScreen:
                                            { screen: HomeScreen },
                                       DetailsScreen:
                                            {screen:DetailsScreen}                            
                                        },                   
                                        )
const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(


{
    Splash: SplashScreen,
    Home:{screen:HomeStack},
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Splash",
    contentComponent: SideMenuScreen
  }
);
```

Comment: can you give me simple example please?